# Syntax for passing a variable in Apache Zeppelin from an Angular paragraph to a Pyspark paragraph?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, data-analysis, apache-zeppelin

I’m trying to do a very simple thing – passing a variable (ideally an array, but string will do) from an Angular paragraph to a pyspark paragraph. Unfortunately I just get the result “None” when printing the value in pyspark.

Setting the variable in my Angular paragraph (I’m using Javascript to do this for reasons related to the bigger project I’m working on and this works fine for passing to another %angular or %spark.spark paragraph):

```
%angular

<form id="main_form"></form>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    angFormScope = angular.element(document.getElementById('main_form')).scope(); // Set Angular scope variable now document is fully loaded and ready
    angFormScope.testvar = "hello"
});
</script>
```

Trying to read the variable in my pyspark paragraph:

```
%spark.pyspark
testvar = z.get("testvar");
print(testvar);
```

Output: `None`

However, getting the variable in another angular paragraph works fine.

I also seem to have access to the Zeppelin context in %pyspark and %python paragraphs, e.g. these work:

```
%spark.pyspark
print(z.z);
```

Output: `org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkZeppelinContext@2cd4a775`

```
%python
# Gets the user's ID from the system, and puts it in the user_ID bound variable
z.z.angularBind("user_ID", z.getInterpreterContext().getAuthenticationInfo().getUser())
```

Output: gives the user id correctly

```
%spark.pyspark
z.z.getInterpreterContext().getNoteId()
```

Output: Gives the note ID correctly.

I notice from the python Zeppelin context source that get() should be available but the function call should be “def get(self, key)” – am I supposed to specify self somehow? https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/master/python/src/main/resources/python/zeppelin_context.py#L58

Think I just need the right syntax here unless there’s a bug in Zeppelin blocking this from working (unfortunately it’s running in a corporate environment with Zeppelin 0.8.2).

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question as I found a workaround, in case it helps others.

1.) Firstly I forgot to do an AngularBind() in the Angular paragraph, to tie the variable to the destination paragraph, for example after the line: `angFormScope.testvar = "hello";` I should have put another line: `angFormScope.z.angularBind('testvar', angFormScope.testvar, paragraph ID here in quotes e.g. '20230616-145326_230977861');`

However, even though that was necessary it made no difference, the pyspark paragraph didn't receive the value.

2.) However, what **did** work was to have an intermediary %spark.spark paragraph to pass the variable through, which looks like this:

```
%spark.spark
val test = z.angular("testvar");
println(test); // Not needed, just for checking we received the value
z.put("testvar", test);
```

z.angular() seems to be needed to receive the value from the %angular paragraph, and then a z.put() is also needed so the %spark.pyspark paragraph can pick it up. The above code goes in a separate paragraph in between the %angular and %spark.pyspark paragraphs, so you have first the %angular paragraph (from my initial post above), then the %spark.spark paragraph with the code above, then finally the %spark.pyspark paragraph (from my initial post above). This works.

z.put doesn't seem to be available in %angular paragraphs and z.angular doesn't seem to be available in %spark.pyspark paragraphs. If either were, then the inbetween %spark.spark paragraph wouldn't be needed (I assume).